# systemd unit how to clear OnFailure setting

Tags: systemd-unit

I had a target t1.target which i cannot modify directly but can only modify through drop-in conf file.  This target has:

```
[Unit]
OnFailure=s1.service
```

On my drop-in conf file I write:

```
[Unit]
OnFailure=
OnFailure=s2.service
```

When t1.target fails, my expectation would be only s2.service started as in my understanding that "OnFailure=" should clear all the services to be run when t1.target fails.  However i saw both s1.service and s2.service are started.

Is there a way to have only s2.service run?  How can OnFailure setting be cleared or can it be cleared?

Thank you very much!